# colvis 1.1.1 - event for showAll/showNone

Tags: datatables

I am using colVis 1.1.1 with DataTables 1.10.0 and recently added the showAll and showNone buttons. The buttons work, but are not firing the stateChange callback (fnStateChange) as documented here: https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/options

Anyone know of a callback that is triggered when showAll or showNone are clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like colVis provides a callback method for the showAll and showNone buttons...

Instead I used the datatables fnDrawCallback, which is triggered when showAll and showNone are clicked.

```
    @showNone = false # initialize this somewhere

    fnDrawCallback: () =>
    # colVis doesn't have a callback for showAll and showNone
    table = $(table_selector)
    headers = $(table).find('thead').find('th')
    if headers.length == 0
      # do stuff here
      @showNone = true
    else if @showNone
      # do other stuff here
      @showNone = false
```